# Group of units of ring of formal power series

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I'm not entirely sure how this is formally shown. The proposition is that, for the ring of formal power series $R[[x]] = \{\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty} r_kx^k | r_k \in R\}$, show that $U(R[[x]]) = \{ u + xf(x) | u \in U(R), f(x) \in R[[x]]\}$.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Let $f,g$ be two power series, with leading coefficients $a_0$ and $b_0$. It is easy to see the leading coefficient  of $fg$ is $a_0b_0$. Therefore, in order to have $fg=1$, you need $a_0b_0=1$, implying $a_0$ is a unit.

On the other hand, suppose $f=u+xh$ for some unit $u$. Then you can show $f$ is a unit in $R[[x]]$ by exhibiting its inverse. Namely, 
$$
\frac1f = \frac{1}{u+xf'}=u^{-1}\cdot\frac1{1+xhu^{-1}}=u^{-1}\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-xhu^{-1})^k
$$
This is using the classic expansion $1/(1+z)=1-z+z^2-z^3+\cdots$.

In general, it is not allowed to take an infinite sum of elements of $R[[x]]$. However, in this case, it is OK. Letting $[x^i]g$ denote the coefficient of $[x^i]$ in $g$, then
$$
[x^i]\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-xhu^{-1})^k=\sum_{k=0}^i[x^i](-xhu^{-1})^k
$$
The reason that the upper limit of $\infty$ can be replaced with $i$ is because whenever $k>i$, all of the powers of $x$ appearing in $(-xf'u^{-1})^k$ are greater than $i$. Therefore, each coefficient of $\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-xhu^{-1})^k$ is a finite sum, so this infinite sum is well defined.

Comment: Precisely the way I would argue, + 1. But I do suggest that calling the nonconstant part of your series $f'$ might lead a careless reader to think you were referring to the derivative. How about $f_1$ instead, or something similar?

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $f=\sum_{k\ge0}a_kx^k\in R[[x]]$ and that $a_0$ is invertible. You want to find $g=\sum_{k\ge0}b_kx^k$ such that $fg=1$.

Since the coefficient of $x^k$ in $fg$ is given by
$$
\sum_{0\le l\le k}a_{k-l}b_l
$$
the condition amounts to saying that $a_0b_0=1$ and, for $k>0$.
$$
\sum_{0\le l\le k}a_{k-l}b_l=0
$$
that is,
$$
b_k=-a_0^{-1}\sum_{0\le l<k}a_{k-l}b_l
$$
This implies that, when you have found $b_0,b_1,\dots,b_{k-1}$, you can also determine (uniquely) $b_k$. Therefore $f$ is invertible.

The converse, that is, $f$ invertible implies $a_0$ invertible, is obvious.